# ERROR Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$cadena' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in

Tags: php7, php5

Tengo la siguiente clase php BD con consultas preparadas:

```php
<?php
class BD {
    //conexion con base de datos
     $cadena = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=idCliente00XX";
     $user = "root";
     $password = "";
     $conn;
     $depuracion = true;
    function open() {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->cadena, $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->conn->exec("set character set utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            if ($this->depuracion)
                echo $e->getMessage();
            $this->conn = NULL;
            die();
        }
    }
    function CerrarConexion() {
        $this->conn = NULL;
    }
//$this->bd->ConsultaPreparada("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE correo=? AND password=? AND tipousuario=?", array($correo, $password, $tipo));
    function ConsultaPreparada($sql, $parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        //echo $sql;
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
                echo var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
            return null;
        }
    }

//this->bd->InsertarRegistrosPreparada("INSERT INTO tabla (id,campo2) VALUES (?,?)", array($ide, $camp)))
    public function InsertarRegistrosPreparada($sql, $parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
            //var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
//$this->bd->ModificarRegistrosPreparada("UPDATE tabla SET titulo = ? WHERE id = ? AND estatus <> ?", array($nombre, $id, 2)))
    public function ModificarRegistrosPreparada($sql, $parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
            // echo var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    //$this->EliminarRegistro("DELETE FROM granja WHERE id_granja=?", array($id));
        public function EliminarRegistro($sql,$parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
            // echo var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
    function ConsultaAsociativaOrdenada($tabla, $parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $tabla);
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
                echo var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
            return null;
        }
    }

    function ModificacionAlter($sql, $parametros) {
        if ($this->conn == NULL)
            $this->open();
        $sentencia = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        //echo $sql;
        if ($sentencia->execute($parametros)) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            if ($this->depuracion)
            // echo var_dump($sentencia->errorInfo());
                return FALSE;
        }

    }

}
?>
```

Accedo sin problemas a la base de datos siempre y cuando las primeras variables de cadena, user, password tengan var antes de ser declaradas. al quitarselas ya no permite conectar y me manda el siguiente error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$cadena' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in
```

estaba trabajando con php 5.5 y mantenia la declaracion de var,ahora necesito poder concatenar dos cadenas y al almacenar su contenido en otra, lo cual me mandaba un error en la variable de concatenacion, me dijeron que la version de php ahora maneja obsoleto la declaracion de var, por lo que supuse que subiendo la version de php me podria realizar la concatenacion sin problemas pero, ya subi la version y me arroja el error en la primer variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner el modificador a los miembros de la clase, tal y como dice la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Las variables pertenecientes a una clase se llaman "propiedades".
>   También se les puede llamar usando otros términos como "atributos" o
>   "campos", pero para los propósitos de esta referencia se va a utilizar
>   "propiedades". Éstas se definen usando una de las palabras reservadas
>   `public`, `protected`, o `private`, seguido de una declaración normal
>   de variable. Esta declaración puede incluir una inicialización, pero
>   esta inicialización debe ser un valor constante, es decir, debe poder
>   ser evaluada durante la compilación y no depender de información
>   generada durante la ejecución.

Por ejemplo, asumiendo que todos los miembros son `private`:

```
class BD {
    //conexion con base de datos
     private $cadena = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=idCliente00XX";
     private $user = "root";
     private $password = "";
     private $conn;
     private $depuracion = true;

    function open() {
    // ... etc
```

Comment: Creía que por defecto las propiedades a nivel de la clase se asumian como public si tú no declarabas su modificador de acceso

Comment: @Aprendiz eso no viene afirmado en el Manual y una prueba empírica te sacará de dudas. Aunque fuera permitido yo lo evitaría. Una clase es un modelo y hay que declarar las cosas de forma explícita.

Comment: Cierto compañero solo era un comentario